# Destroy most sessions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple battle script for my game, but after the battle and all, I don't want the player to be able to click refresh and fight the monster again.. or be able to hit submit over and over to keep getting the rewards for winning.. so what would I need to do so after the person hit's the attack button and the battle shows the results, to make it so this can't happen? if I try to session_destroy() that logs the player out aswell as fixing the problem :/

Here's my code any help?

```
   if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {

     $player=$_SESSION['username'];
     $playerstats1="SELECT * from users where username='$player'";
     $playerstats2=mysql_query($playerstats1) or die ("Could not find player");
     $playerstats3=mysql_fetch_array($playerstats2);

     $pokemonstat1="SELECT * from user_pokemon where belongsto='$player' AND slot='1'";
     $pokemonstat2=mysql_query($pokemonstat1) or die ("Could not find pokemon");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pokemonstat2)){

     $yourmonster="SELECT * from pokemon where name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
     $yourmonster2=mysql_query($yourmonster) or die ("Cannot select battle the pokemon");
     $yourmonster3=mysql_fetch_array($yourmonster2);


     $monstername=$_SESSION['pokemon'];
     $monstername=strip_tags($monstername);
     $selmonster="SELECT * from pokemon where name='$monstername'";
     $selmonster2=mysql_query($selmonster) or die ("Cannot select battle the pokemon");
     $selmonster3=mysql_fetch_array($selmonster2);

           $totalskill=$yourmonster3[att] * $row['level'] + $selmonster3[att] * 5;
           $randomnumber=rand(1,$totalskill);
           if($randomnumber<=$yourmonster3[att] * $row['level'])
           {
             echo "<center>";  
             echo "you have won!";
             echo "</center>";

           } else {
               echo "<center>";
               echo "you have lost!";
               echo "</center>";
           }
         }
    }
```

Updated again.

```
   $battle_id = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    echo $battle_id;
    // $battle_id would be something like 9a8ab59df7079208843086e9b49a7862

    // initialise the battle log
    if(!isset($_SESSION['battle_log']) || !is_array($_SESSION['battle_log']))
    {
        $_SESSION['battle_log'] = array();
    }

   // Check if the battle hasn't been played
   if(!in_array($battle_id, $_SESSION['battle_log']))
   {
       // add played battle to the log

       // ... your battle code goes here



    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {

     $player=$_SESSION['username'];
     $playerstats1="SELECT * from users where username='$player'";
     $playerstats2=mysql_query($playerstats1) or die ("Could not find player");
     $playerstats3=mysql_fetch_array($playerstats2);

     $pokemonstat1="SELECT * from user_pokemon where belongsto='$player' AND slot='1'";
     $pokemonstat2=mysql_query($pokemonstat1) or die ("Could not find pokemon");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pokemonstat2)){





     $yourmonster="SELECT * from pokemon where name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
     $yourmonster2=mysql_query($yourmonster) or die ("Cannot select battle the pokemon");
     $yourmonster3=mysql_fetch_array($yourmonster2);


     $monstername=$_SESSION['pokemon'];
     $monstername=strip_tags($monstername);
     $selmonster="SELECT * from pokemon where name='$monstername'";
     $selmonster2=mysql_query($selmonster) or die ("Cannot select battle the pokemon");
     $selmonster3=mysql_fetch_array($selmonster2);

           $totalskill=$yourmonster3[att] * $row['level'] + $selmonster3[att] * 5;
           $randomnumber=rand(1,$totalskill);
           if($randomnumber<=$yourmonster3[att] * $row['level'])
           {
             echo "<center>";  
             echo "you have won!";
             echo "</center>";

           } else {
               echo "<center>";
               echo "you have lost!";
               echo "</center>";
           }
         }
    }
          $_SESSION['battle_log'][] = $battle_id;
   }else {

      echo "Don't try to cheat...";
   }
```

Comment: You could forward them to a different page and display the results there. As well as store a time or something in the session that prevents them from doing the battle again until the stored time.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set a value in the session indicating that the battle has already been played by the user. You can then check against that value to see if your user has played the battle already.

The value you would save in the session would be unique, like the Battle ID. If this is something you don't have then you can create a unique battle reference by making a signature of all the unique values in the battle. Like so:-

```
    $battle_id = md5($player.$row['pokemon'].$monstername);
    // $battle_id would be something like 9a8ab59df7079208843086e9b49a7862
```

At the start of your script initialise a log of all battles played:-

```
    // initialise the battle log
    if(!isset($_SESSION['battle_log']) || !is_array($_SESSION['battle_log']))
    {
        $_SESSION['battle_log'] = array();
    }
```

Then before the start of any battle check if it hasn't already been played

```
   // Check if the battle hasn't been played
   if(!in_array($battle_id, $_SESSION['battle_log']))
   {
       // ... your battle code goes here

       // add played battle to the log
       $_SESSION['battle_log'][] = $battle_id;
   }
```

So something along these lines should work:-

```
// initialise the battle log
if(!isset($_SESSION['battle_log']) || !is_array($_SESSION['battle_log']))
{
    $_SESSION['battle_log'] = array();
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $player=$_SESSION['username'];
    $playerstats1="SELECT * from users where username='$player'";
    $playerstats2=mysql_query($playerstats1) or die ("Could not find player");
    $playerstats3=mysql_fetch_array($playerstats2);

    $pokemonstat1="SELECT * from user_pokemon where belongsto='$player' AND slot='1'";
    $pokemonstat2=mysql_query($pokemonstat1) or die ("Could not find pokemon");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pokemonstat2))
    {
        $yourmonster="SELECT * from pokemon where name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
        $yourmonster2=mysql_query($yourmonster) or die ("Cannot select battle the pokemon");
        $yourmonster3=mysql_fetch_array($yourmonster2);

        $monstername=$_SESSION['pokemon'];
        $monstername=strip_tags($monstername);
        $selmonster="SELECT * from pokemon where name='$monstername'";
        $selmonster2=mysql_query($selmonster) or die ("Cannot select battle the pokemon");
        $selmonster3=mysql_fetch_array($selmonster2);

        // generate the battle id based on the unique battle details
        $battle_id = md5($player.$row['pokemon'].$monstername);

        $totalskill=$yourmonster3[att] * $row['level'] + $selmonster3[att] * 5;
        $randomnumber=rand(1,$totalskill);
        if($randomnumber<=$yourmonster3[att] * $row['level'])
        {
            echo "<center>you have won!</center>";
        } else {
            echo "<center>you have lost!</center>";
        }

        // Check if the battle hasn't been played
        if(!in_array($battle_id, $_SESSION['battle_log']))
        {
            // any code below will only be run once per battle
            // ...

            // add played battle to the log
            $_SESSION['battle_log'][] = $battle_id;
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:*** Bare in mind that a session is only temporary so once the session is destroyed all history of battles played is lost so persist the data. You could create a `battle` table to do this.

Comment: I really don't know how to do this :/

Comment: I have updated my answer with example code to help

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do all that but, I still can't seem to get it to work :/

Comment: I will post what I have so far in the original post, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This looks ok to me. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: It never gives the result of the battle it just goes streight to don't try to cheat.

Comment: Leave the `initialise the battle log` code at the top of the script. Move the rest of it within your while loop and before `if($randomnumber<=$yourmonster3[att] * $row['level'])` so you don't calculate the values of the battle if it already has been replayed. You will also need to reset the session since the battle id may already be in your log

Comment: I tried, but I don't think I'm doing it right :/ I'll update my code again. I'm sorry I'm pretty new to all of this would you mind putting the code where it needs to go for me I've been at this for hours and just don't know anymore XD

Comment: Now it generates the battle results, but it doesn't stop you from repeating the battle over and over :/

Comment: I think I figured out my own way to do it, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Generate a special key before the fight starts and appoint it into a session. Also push it to HTML as a hidden input in your HTML form.

When the user submits the form, check both Submit and the special key.

If they match, user played the battle once. When you handle your battle scripts, make sure to remove/regenerate the key.

If user press F5 and repost the form once again, it will not work because key is invalid. They need to refresh page to obtain new key.

As for `session_destroy()`, you don't need this. Just `unset` the appropriate session, or give that session a new value.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're saying, but I'll go ahead and give it a try XD do you mean something like this?  I will update my post with what I think you are saying.

Comment: Alright, I understand what you are saying now, but I don't know how to do it.